# LEFT JOIN vs Stacked Left Join

Tags: sql, join, nested

I wanted to ask whats the difference between those two queries:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID, 
    OrderDetails.Quantity, Products.ProductName
FROM
    Customers
LEFT JOIN 
    (Orders 
LEFT JOIN  
    (OrderDetails 
LEFT JOIN 
    Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
    ) ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
  ) ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    Customers.CustomerName;
```

Vs

```
SELECT 
    Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID, 
    OrderDetails.Quantity, Products.ProductName
FROM 
    Customers
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN 
    Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
GROUP BY 
    Customers.CustomerName;
```

Tested here
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join

From what I can see one selects the first of multiple entries, one selects the last of multiple entries, but is that all?

From my point of view the not nested LEFT Join is way easier to read and to understand. Is there any downside of using it?

Comment: I believe Access SQL requires the bracket notation. For other DBMS they're identical.

Comment: Your comment about "select the first of multiple entries" is mis-founded.  Your test is running MySQL, which allows you to do `SELECT a, b, c FROM x GROUP BY a`.  Other dialects *(and later versions of, or options within, MySQL)* prevent this and *require* you to `GROUP BY a, b, c`.  In your case, because each customer name is associated to multiple orders, MySQL is ***arbitrarily*** picking one OrderID, one Quantity, one Product, etc.  They're not even guaranteed to be related to each other. *(It's not related to the LEFT JOINs)*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: The first query does not run. What DBMS are you using? Also "selects the first of multiple entries" & "selects the last of multiple entries" are not clear. Please edit your post to clearly say what you mean. Whatever you mean, it's not even clear whether you think they return the same result. And whether you do or not, why? Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. Then learn how to use group by.

Comment: @philipxy Click on his link and paste in the code.  It certainly does run.  In MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the incorrect use of `GROUP BY`.  The only unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should be in the `GROUP BY`.

The rest of this answer addresses the point about joins.

Your second query is interpreted as:

```
FROM (((Customers c LEFT JOIN
        Orders o
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ) LEFT JOIN
       OrderDetails 
       ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
      ) LEFT JOIN
      Products p
      ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
```

The parentheses can affect the interpretation.  But what effect?  Essentially, you have:

```
(((c left join o) left join od) left join p)
```

versus

```
c left join (o left join (od left join p)))
```

Both keep all records in `c`, regardless of matches in the second.  In this case, the two versions do the same thing.  But for a particular reason -- the `on` conditions are strictly chained (that is, c to o, o to od, od to p).  If `p` where joined to `o` instead of `od`, then subtle differences can occur.

What are the subtle differences?  Two things can differ:

- Whether columns from a particular table are `NULL` or have values.
- Whether rows get duplicated, due to multiple matches between two tables.

In practice, I don't fine parentheses particularly useful.  If I can about `JOIN` order, I use an explicit subquery or CTE>

Comment: As you said, with the "strictly chained" order of the predicates, the parentheses don't make a functional difference in the OP's case.  Yet the OP is getting different results, and mistakenly believes it's defined behaviour related to the joins.  It is actually the result of MySQL's arbitrary behaviour when using `SELECT a, b, c FROM x GROUP BY a` - Which happens to be influenced by the parentheses, but not in a manner that delivers results that are guaranteed to be deterministic.  *(In fact, this is evidence of the absence of such a guarantee.)*